# What Kind of Layer to Add Building Info?

Tags: layers, classification

I am new to QGIS (two days ago) and have been given a task to identify buildings, store info on them (building year, color, road type) in a layer and then export the info in a CSV file. I have fuddled around with plugins and youtube videos for two days and am completely lost. I have no idea what type of layer to use, how to store data and export.

They have given me multiple choice options. For example, for building color they have given me 7 possible colors. I can find the building using the street view plugin, but do no know how or what layer to add to attach this information to the building. I have added an openstreet osm file to view a layer containing multipolygons, so I can see the building and even see some of the classifications I need.

Any advice?

Comment: To me this seems to be a too difficult task for someone without QGIS knowledge (or GIS knowledge in general). I'd recommend doing some general GIS training first. That said, for us to answer your question, it would help us to know what type of data your input data is. Maybe you could post a sample of it here?

Comment: They have given me a multiple choice options. For example, for building color they have given me 7 possible years. I can find the building using the street view plugin, but do no know how or what layer to add to attach this information to the building. I have added an openstreet osm file to view a layer containing multipolygons, so I can see the building and even see some of the classifications I need.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a one vector layer, which have a property table. Property table maybe have a several fields about building, for example building year, color, road type. 
Once all data is stored in a vector layer, it is easy to export to csv file in QGIS.